# mysql server restart failed

Tags: mysql, apt

I want to recover my mysql root password so I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/recover-mysql-root-password.html) and stopped the mysql server . when I am trying to start it its show a error message and won't start. I believe the error is due to read only file system.

1. Is their any other way of restarting the mysql server

> ```
> root@web01:/home/# /etc/init.d/mysql stop
> Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld
>
>
>
>
> ^Z
> [2]+  Stopped                 /etc/init.d/mysql stop
> root@web01:/home/# mysql
> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
> root@web01:/home/# 
> root@web01:/home/# mysql -u root
> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
> root@web01:/home/# mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
> [3] 7784
> root@web01:/home/# 120830 08:20:56 mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
> rm: cannot remove `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid': Read-only file system
> 120830 08:20:57 mysqld_safe Fatal error: Can't remove the pid file:
> /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
> Please remove it manually and start /usr/bin/mysqld_safe again;
> mysqld daemon not started
>
> [3]   Exit 1                  mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
> root@web01:/home/# mysql -u root
> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
> root@web01:/home/# /etc/init.d/mysqld start
> bash: /etc/init.d/mysqld: No such file or directory
> root@web01:/home# /etc/init.d/mysql start
> Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . .
>  . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
> root@web01:/home# 
> root@web01:/home# /etc/init.d/mysql start
> Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
> root@web01:/home# /etc/init.d/mysql restart
> Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld.
> Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
> root@web01:/home# ^C
> root@web01:/home#
> ```

NOTE: I am facing the readonly file system error which I have asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46628/not-able-to-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-read-only)  .

Answer (score 1):

umount, chkfs ?

mount -rw

First of all solve problem with filesystem, and start mysql only after that

Comment: Please check my NOTE and if possible answer to the file system error [THERE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46628/not-able-to-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-read-only) and after that please help me with this here . Thanks

Comment: You need no help HERE. After fix read only, mysql will work.